# CSS3 horizontal fading drop shadow with specific stops?

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to use pure CSS to have a slight dropshadow that lays over a tab. I want it to fade out on the ends at 20% and 80%. I've been trying to acheive this for some time now, but finding myself not happy with the results so far.

Here's an image of what I want to have:

[image: Shadow Tab]

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
    <span>Button Text</span>
    <span class="buttonshadow"></span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 6px 16px 7px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #5CBCEC;
    border-color: #5CBCEC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
}
.buttonshadow {
    width: 120%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10%;
}
.buttonshadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -3%, ellipse cover, rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.2), rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.0) 40%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(97, 97, 97, 0) 70%);
}
```

Here's my current fiddle so far: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cexeh/rLsbC/)

Clearly this does not look the same. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: You could just use an image (possibly svg).

Comment: If you want to have the shadow be a constant height over the button and only fade out at both sides, than just _one_ elliptical gradient won’t do IMHO. I’d try with just a _linear_ gradient for the span over the whole width of the button, and then add a faded shadow via an elliptical gradient on both sides using `:before`/`:after` elements on the span …

Comment: @bjb568 if I wanted to just use an image, I would have just used an image. The point is to NOT use an image.

Comment: @CBroe Sounds interesting... care to post a working example?

Comment: That was only a comment and not an answer for a reason ;-) Basically just me spitballin’, but too lazy to actually try it out at this time of night (in my location).

Comment: @Ce. Inline SVGs aren't as much imagey as new, shiny, and pathy. Vector!, I say.

Comment: @bjb568 yeah I agree. I was just curious if this was possible via a semi-simple CSS technique. Basically like combining gradient with stops at 20% and 80% and having the vertical fade of a drop shadow.

Comment: @Ce. Oh, ok. But you will still have to add a span for it.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand the problem correctly you want the gradient outside the button on the edges.

problem lies in the `.buttonshadow` and `.buttonshadow:before`

I changed it to this

```
.buttonshadow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -25px;
}
.buttonshadow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 130%;
    height: 5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -3%, ellipse cover, rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.2), rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.0) 40%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 0%, rgba(55, 55, 55, 1), rgba(97, 97, 97, 0) 80%);
}
```

Check fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rLsbC/1/

you can then fiddle around with the gradient to get more what you want.
Hope this helps!

Note: If you want to change the width of the gradient change the width in `.buttonshadow:before` and the left attribute in `.buttonshadow`

Comment: This is really close to what I already have, but the issue I seem to be trying to conquer here is the quick fade-out as seen in the image... instead of a gradual one.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution that may work for you.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLsbC/2/)**

In order to get the fading at the ends I had to squish the radial gradient down a bit, and then position it to look right. I added it to the `.btn` class instead of a separate element.

CSS:

```
.btn:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120%;
    height: 5px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -10%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 85%); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *[me, earlier via comments]* I’d try with just a linear gradient for the span over the whole width of the button, and then add a faded shadow via an elliptical gradient on both sides using `:before`/ `:after` elements on the span …

OK, I gave it a go now – http://jsfiddle.net/rLsbC/3/

Sorry, it’s Firefox only for now as I didn’t bother with vendor prefixes for other browsers – but to add those should be not a big deal. (For those that actually support radial gradients anyway.)

I replaced the shadow in the `span` element itself with a linear gradient,

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%,
  rgba(97, 97, 97, 0) 100%);
```

and then added positioned `:before`/`:after` with an elliptical radial gradient positioned at the top right resp. top left corner of those generated elements, like this

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(top right, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
  rgba(97, 97, 97, 0) 50%);
```

Had to make the span element itself a little higher to get the linear gradient and the elliptical ones stuck to the sides of it to match up.

If you take that as a basis and play around with the specific values of the gradients (and maybe the width/position of the generated elements), you should be able to get very close to what you want.